# How do I reverse engineer this code to convert a binary graphic table to a editable png?

Tags: java, android

I'm working re-spriting this android game and the sprites are all in one file called gt, this is the code from the apk that converts what I assume is the byte code file into actual images.

It takes one parameter which is the path to that file.

Java isn't really my language so I was hoping someone could help me figure out what this code is doing and how I can use it to convert the file into something that I can edit like a png.

This is the corresponding source code:

```
    public static void readGraphicsTable(String paramString)
{
    InputStream localInputStream = Util.getResourceAsStream(paramString);
    if (localInputStream == null)
    {
    HG.logWarning("Config file not found: " + paramString);
    return;
    }
    int j;
    int k;
    for (;;)
    {
    try
    {
        paramString = new DataInputStream(localInputStream);
        j = paramString.readShort();
        k = paramString.readShort();
        if ((j != 18260) && (k != 1281))
        {
        try
        {
            localInputStream.close();
            return;
        }
        catch (Throwable paramString)
        {
            return;
        }
        createFontOffsets();
        }
    }
    catch (Throwable paramString)
    {
        label156:
        paramString = paramString;
        HG.handleError(paramString, "Gfx.readGraphicsTable()");
        try
        {
        localInputStream.close();
        return;
        }
        catch (Throwable paramString)
        {
        return;
        }
        k = paramString.readShort();
        colors = new int[k];
        j = 0;
        if (j >= k) {
        continue;
        }
        colors[j] = paramString.readInt();
        j += 1;
        continue;
        k = paramString.readShort();
        fonts = new Font[k];
        fontOffsets = (int[][])Array.newInstance(Integer.TYPE, new int[] { k, 4 });
        j = 0;
        if (j >= k) {
        continue;
        }
        m = paramString.readByte();
        if (m != -1) {
        continue;
        }
        fonts[j] = Font.getDefaultFont();
        fontOffsets[j][0] = paramString.readByte();
        fontOffsets[j][1] = paramString.readByte();
        fontOffsets[j][2] = paramString.readByte();
        fontOffsets[j][3] = paramString.readByte();
        j += 1;
        continue;
        fonts[j] = Font.getFont(m & 0x60, m & 0x7, m & 0x18);
        continue;
    }
    finally {}
    j = paramString.readShort();
    if (j == -1) {
        break label1144;
    }
    k = paramString.readShort();
    switch (j)
    {
    case 17231: 
        paramString.skip(k);
    }
    }
    for (;;)
    {
    int m;
    try
    {
        localInputStream.close();
        throw paramString;
        k = paramString.readShort();
        imageTable = new short[k + 4][];
        images = new Image[k + 4];
        j = 0;
        if (j < k)
        {
        m = (short)paramString.readByte();
        if (m == -1) {
            break label1160;
        }
        arrayOfShort = imageTable;
        arrayOfShort1 = new short[12];
        arrayOfShort[j] = arrayOfShort1;
        m = (short)(m << 8);
        if ((m & 0x200) != 0)
        {
            int i = paramString.readShort();
            System.arraycopy(imageTable[i], 0, arrayOfShort1, 0, arrayOfShort1.length);
            arrayOfShort1[7] = ((short)(arrayOfShort1[7] | m));
            arrayOfShort1[10] = i;
            break label1160;
        }
        n = paramString.readByte();
        int i1 = paramString.readByte();
        arrayOfShort1[7] = ((short)(m | n));
        arrayOfShort1[2] = ((short)(i1 >> 4 & 0xF));
        arrayOfShort1[3] = ((short)(i1 >> 0 & 0xF));
        arrayOfShort1[4] = ((short)paramString.readByte());
        arrayOfShort1[5] = paramString.readShort();
        arrayOfShort1[6] = paramString.readShort();
        arrayOfShort1[8] = paramString.readShort();
        paramString.readUTF();
        if ((m & 0x100) == 0) {
            break label1160;
        }
        arrayOfShort1[10] = paramString.readShort();
        arrayOfShort1[11] = ((short)paramString.readByte());
        break label1160;
        }
        short[][] arrayOfShort = imageTable;
        short[] arrayOfShort1 = new short[12];
        arrayOfShort['?'] = arrayOfShort1;
        arrayOfShort1[7] = 0;
        arrayOfShort1[10] = 0;
        arrayOfShort1[2] = 1;
        arrayOfShort1[3] = 1;
        arrayOfShort1[4] = 3;
        arrayOfShort1[5] = 0;
        arrayOfShort1[6] = 0;
        arrayOfShort1[8] = 0;
        arrayOfShort = imageTable;
        arrayOfShort1 = new short[12];
        arrayOfShort['?'] = arrayOfShort1;
        arrayOfShort1[7] = 0;
        arrayOfShort1[10] = 0;
        arrayOfShort1[2] = 1;
        arrayOfShort1[3] = 1;
        arrayOfShort1[4] = 3;
        arrayOfShort1[5] = 0;
        arrayOfShort1[6] = 0;
        arrayOfShort1[8] = 0;
        arrayOfShort = imageTable;
        arrayOfShort1 = new short[12];
        arrayOfShort['?'] = arrayOfShort1;
        arrayOfShort1[7] = 0;
        arrayOfShort1[10] = 0;
        arrayOfShort1[2] = 4;
        arrayOfShort1[3] = 1;
        arrayOfShort1[4] = 3;
        arrayOfShort1[5] = 0;
        arrayOfShort1[6] = 0;
        arrayOfShort1[8] = 0;
        arrayOfShort = imageTable;
        arrayOfShort1 = new short[12];
        arrayOfShort['?'] = arrayOfShort1;
        arrayOfShort1[7] = 0;
        arrayOfShort1[10] = 0;
        arrayOfShort1[2] = 1;
        arrayOfShort1[3] = 1;
        arrayOfShort1[4] = 3;
        arrayOfShort1[5] = 0;
        arrayOfShort1[6] = 0;
        arrayOfShort1[8] = 0;
        break;
        k = paramString.readShort();
        frameTable = new short[k * 7];
        j = 0;
        break label1167;
        frameTable[(m + 2)] = ((short)paramString.readUnsignedByte());
        frameTable[(m + 3)] = ((short)paramString.readUnsignedByte());
        frameTable[(m + 0)] = ((short)paramString.readUnsignedByte());
        frameTable[(m + 1)] = ((short)paramString.readUnsignedByte());
        frameTable[(m + 4)] = ((short)paramString.readByte());
        frameTable[(m + 5)] = ((short)paramString.readByte());
        frameTable[(m + 6)] = ((short)paramString.readByte());
        break label1208;
        frameTable[(m + 2)] = paramString.readShort();
        frameTable[(m + 3)] = paramString.readShort();
        frameTable[(m + 0)] = paramString.readShort();
        frameTable[(m + 1)] = paramString.readShort();
        frameTable[(m + 4)] = paramString.readShort();
        frameTable[(m + 5)] = paramString.readShort();
        frameTable[(m + 6)] = ((short)paramString.readByte());
        break label1208;
        m = paramString.readShort();
        animationTable = new short[m][];
        j = 0;
        if (j >= m) {
        break;
        }
        int n = paramString.readShort();
        arrayOfShort = animationTable;
        arrayOfShort1 = new short[n + 2];
        arrayOfShort[j] = arrayOfShort1;
        k = 0;
        if (k >= n + 2) {
        break label1215;
        }
        arrayOfShort1[k] = paramString.readShort();
        k += 1;
        continue;
        paramString.skip(k);
        break;
        try
        {
        label1144:
        localInputStream.close();
        return;
        }
        catch (Throwable paramString)
        {
        return;
        }
    }
    catch (Throwable localThrowable)
    {
        continue;
    }
    break label156;
    label1160:
    j += 1;
    continue;
    label1167:
    while (j < k)
    {
        m = j * 7;
        switch (8)
        {
        }
        label1208:
        j += 1;
    }
    break;
    label1215:
    j += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you see the number of lines ? No one will reverse it for you^^ If you really to do that, take time

Comment: @azro - A more accurate statement would be that nobody is likely to do it unless you paid them some money to do the work for you.   Especially since, there is some doubt that what the IP is doing is legal ....